# Emacs flashes when changing buffer with `ido-switch-buffer`

Tags: buffers, python, debugging, ido, ibuffer

When I change buffer via `ido-switch-buffer` and enter a python buffer my entire Emacs flashes visually for a second. If I handle other files the same way, it does not. What can be the reason for that? the related part of my config looks as follows

```
;; Turn switch-to-buffer into ibuffer
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x b") 'ibuffer)
;; expert-mode
;; If you feel like you know how ibuffer works and need not to be asked for confirmation after every serious command, enable this as follows.
(setq ibuffer-expert t)

;; * IDO
(setq ido-create-new-buffer 'always)
(setq ido-everywhere t)
(setq ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length nil)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
(setq ido-enable-prefix nil)
(setq ido-handle-duplicate-virtual-buffers 2)
(setq ido-max-prospects 10)
(setq ido-use-filename-at-point 'guess)
(setq ido-use-virtual-buffers t)
(setq ido-default-file-method 'selected-window)
(use-package ido-completing-read+ :ensure t)
(ido-mode 1)

;; ** IDO vertical
(use-package ido-vertical-mode
  :ensure t
  :diminish
  :init
  (ido-vertical-mode 1))
(setq ido-vertical-define-keys 'C-n-and-C-p-only)

;; ** IDO Switch buffer
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'ido-switch-buffer)
```

Comment: Please try to narrow the code you present to show only what is necessary to reproduce the problem, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). I removed some of it, but please remove as much as possible that is extraneous to the problem. And perhaps describe a bit better what the "flashing" looks like.

Comment: A wild guess is that the flashing indicates an error being raised. Be sure to include all code necessary to repro the problem, starting with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: @drew I think that the init file is in `org-mode` format is salient information and should not have been edited out

Comment: @nega: The question didn't say that the users "config" (which was an org file) is used as an Emacs init file. I was assuming this was just the OP's way of communicating his config code to us. But maybe you're right, and that's the problem (or part of it). If that's the case, then please consider posting an answer about that being the problem (or at least salient). And in that case, you will want to undo that part of the edit. Thx.